# Scale box to fill with offset

Tags: geometry

As shown in the illustration, we have a photo (blue) and a frame (red) that will crop the photo.

The photo has a focal point. We have already translated it such that the focal point aligns with the center of the frame.

Vector d is the smallest distance from the sides of the photo to the corresponding sides of the frame. This value can be positive (outward) or negative (inward).

Now we want to scale the photo proportionally, anchored at frameCenter, to fill the frame.

The scaling anchor will always remain at the same position as the rectangle scales.

If we were scaling anchored at photoCenter, the answer would be `1 + 2 * d / photoWidth`, but offsetting the anchor changes how the edges move. Plus that would shift our focal point in the frame, which we don't want.

What is the correct scaling percent?

Added context: I've run into this issue while trying to automatically place a set of photos in frames with a Photoshop script. We added guides in the photos to indicate the focal point so that the subjects stay in frame regardless of changes in the frame's aspect ratio.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for the reply. But you've only introduced more uncertainty, as I can think of no further understanding nor context to add.

Comment: Consider answering the following questions in an [edit] then: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: @Shaun I've already answered those as I'm able. It's a practical question with the given context of a photo scaling to fill a frame with an offset anchor. All of that is clearly laid out. A sample answer (and tried approach) was provided as the equation for scaling anchored at photoCenter. I can add more of my attempted approaches, but I don't want to complicate the question with red herrings.

Comment: I agree that you have rather well explained your issue. A general consideration : Let us write (x,y), resp (x',y') for the coordinates of a pixel and its transformed pixel in the the *same* reference frame for example the blue frame : the formulas are necessarily of the form : $\begin{cases}x'=ax+b\\y'=cx+d\end{cases}$ but with which (fixed) coefficients $a,b,c,d$ ? You need for this purpose to find two points and their images for example the 2 North-West points and the 2 South-East points. In this way you will have 4 constraints for 4 unknowns.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. I've hopefully isolated the problem to solving along the x-axis for simplicity. We have coordinates for the two centerpoints and distances for the widths and label d. I could add the x coordinates of the right edges as a shortcut if that helps. It does appear to be some sort of linear relationship, as you've mentioned.

Comment: It's not that the question is not clear. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: According to your sketch, the photo (looks like a rectangle) and the frame (looks like a square) have two different shapes. If that is the actual case, the photo will be distorted when you try to scale it to fit the frame. Can you tell us what your want to achieve by scaling, whether to include whole photo or only a part of it inside the frame?

Comment: We want to proportionally scale the photo (same percentage for height & width) so as to perfectly cover the red frame with the blue photo while keeping the focal point of the photo in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to try, we can give you a scale factor, which, we think, is the one you are looking for. If $\pmb{w}$ and $\pmb{a}$ are the width of the photo and the horizontal distance between its center and the focal point respectively, then the scale factor for the scenario depicted in your sketch is given by
$$1+\dfrac{2d}{w-2a}.\tag{0}$$

This makes the width of the frame equal to
$$w-2a+2d.$$

Furthermore, you can obtain the scale factor, which is mentioned in your problem statement for the case focal point coinciding with center, by substituting $a=0$ in $(0)$.

The following text was added after OP stated that expression $(0)$ gives the sought scale factor.

$\underline{\bf{The\space Proof}}:$

Scaling is one the simple forms of affine transformation.  In geometry, an affine transformation is formally described as mapping of an object from one affine space to another or the same space while preserving affine combinations such as lines and distance ratios. Scaling is performed from a point called the invariant point, which remains unchanged by the operation. All the other points on the original object are mapped to distinctly different points on the scaled version of the object.  If we join a point on the original object to its corresponding point on the scaled version by a straight line, that line passes through the invariant point of scaling. We are going to use this property of scaling in our proof.

In the case of general two dimensional non-uniform scaling from a given point, coordinates of which are $\left(x_i,\space y_i\right)$, the transformation can be expressed using two linear equations as shown below.
$$\begin{array}{c}
x’=s_x\left(x-x_i\right)+x_i\space\\
y'=s_y\left(y-y_i\right)+y_i\space, 
\end{array}\tag{1}$$
where $\left(x,\space y\right)$ is the coordinates of the point on an object being scaled and $\left(x’,\space y’\right)$ is the corresponding point on the scaled object. Furthermore, $s_x$ and $s_y$ are the scaling factors in the direction of $x\text{-axis}$ and $y\text{-axis}$ respectively.

In the case of uniform scaling, in which an object is stretched by the same amount in all directions, we can express $s_x$ and $s_y$ using a common scale factor $s$ as,
$$s_x=s_y=s.$$

Now, we can write (1) as,
$$\begin{array}{c}
x’=s\left(x-x_i\right)+x_i\space\\ 
y’=s\left(y-y_i\right)+y_i\space. 
\end{array}\tag{2}$$

Therefore, if we know the $x\text{-coordinate}$ of a point on the original object and the $x\text{-coordinate}$ of the corresponding point on the scaled object, we can determine the scale factor $s$ from equation (2) as,
$$ s=\dfrac{x’-x_i}{x-x_i}.\tag{3}$$

[image: PhotoFrame]

Consider $\mathrm{Fig.\space 0}$, where $ABCD$ is the original object (photo) and $PQRT$ is the frame. The center of $ABCD$ is $O$. You want to capture a certain part of the scaled version of the photo inside the frame, so that the position of the given focal point $F$ of the photo remain where it was. This same task can be described as scaling the edge $CD$ from the invariant point $F$ so that it mapped onto the edge $RT$ of the frame.

Let’s draw a perpendicular line to $CD$ through $F$ to meet $CD$ and $RT$ at $M$ and $N$ respectively. According to the property described above, $N$ is the point on $RT$, which corresponds to the point $M$ on $CD$. Now, we need to find the $x\text{-coordinates}$ of this pair of points in terms of $a$, $d$, and $w$.
$$x_m=\dfrac{w}{2}-a+x_F\qquad\qquad x_n=\dfrac{w}{2}-a+d+x_F$$

From equation (3), we have,

$$ s=\dfrac{x_n-x_F}{x_m-x_F}=\dfrac{\dfrac{w}{2}-a+d+x_F -x_F}{\dfrac{w}{2}-a+x_F -x_F}=\dfrac{\dfrac{w}{2}-a+d }{\dfrac{w}{2}-a}=1+\dfrac{2d}{w-2a}.$$

$\underline{{\bf{ How\space to\space Choose\space}} \pmb{d}}:$

Yes, you are right. You need to calculate the scale factors for all four edges. The largest scale factor is the one to use to do the scaling. However, a close look at the expression $(0)$, shows you that the value of signed $d$ itself indicates which $d$ to use to calculate the correct scale factor. If all four $d$ s are negative, choose the $d$ which has the smallest absolute value. Otherwise, the largest positive $d$ is the candidate.

[image: ScaleUp]

[image: ScaleDown]

Comment: The extra details and visuals are very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found an equation that so far is fitting all of my data. If anyone decides to add a more rigorous proof, I'll mark that as the answer instead.

$scaleFactor = \frac{ frameRight - frameCenter }{ photoWidth - frameCenter + photoLeft }$

I arrived at this by manually scaling rectangles (photo stand-ins) with different anchor offsets to known scaleFactors and then measuring where the photoRight ended up. This also helped to see the relationships between the values, giving me enough intuition to match those measurements with the following equation using trial and error. The equation above is merely this one rearranged so as to isolate scaleFactor.

$frameRight = frameCenter + scaleFactor( photoWidth - frameCenter + photoLeft ) $

For anyone trying to apply this, you can use this equation for when the right or left side needs the least scaling. If scaling for the left, zero out the photoWidth value. Swap photoWidth for photoHeight, top for left, and bottom for right in the vertical cases, assuming your origin is top-left (which it is, in both Photoshop and photopea.com).

The next trick is working out accurately which side to look at for the scaling. I haven't fully solved that (and I don't think this is the place for me to do so), but I know that it's some combination of the starting distances (d in the diagram), the aspect ratio, and the ratio of the focal point across the photoWidth. Correction: just calculate the scaleFactor for all sides and pick the largest.

Comment: The equation for the scale factor you give  in your answer is exactly equal to the expression we gave in our answer.

Comment: Thanks @YNK, I was originally having trouble applying your equation, but that was on me for struggling with abstractness. Pretty cool that we came up with different approaches to the same result!

Comment: A proof and two examples were added to our answer. We did not use Photoshop to do the scaling, instead use GeoGebra